# Skype overwrites ~/.config/Skype/Skype.conf settings on each incoming call (Ubuntu)

Tags: skype, ubuntu-14.04, cinnamon

I have encountered the "hidden answer pop-up" issue while using skype for linux on multiple monitors.

I found a way to configure where the popup appears by editing `~/.config/Skype/Skype.conf`, and that works while running "test" notifications.

Unfortunately, whenever I receive a real Skype call, Skype decides to ignore the settings in the config file, and then when the call ends, it re-writes the config file with the broken settings again.

The settings that it writes are:

```
[CallView]
geometry=@ByteArray(\x1\xd9\xd0\xcb\0\x1\0\0\0\0\x5\xd7\0\0\x1\xe3\0\0\t\x96\0\0\x3\xea\0\0\x5\xd7\0\0\x1\xe3\0\0\t\x96\0\0\x3\xea\0\0\0\x2\0\0)

[IncomingCallPopup]
position=@Point(792 263)
```

Which puts the "Incoming Call" popup somewhere off screen. I can change that setting to this:

```
[IncomingCallPopup]
position=@Point(1600 263)
```

Which makes the popup appear at the correct location while doing a "test" notification. Unfortunately, as soon as I ask someone to ring me, it changes that setting back again.

Comment: Try `sudo chattr +i filename`. This makes the file unchangeable.

Comment: Not sure that that'll work - Skype seems to reset it's config internally, and then actually writes the file at the end of the call. Making the file read-only likely wouldn't stop Skype from changing its internal config at will.

Comment: Who said anything about making the file read-only? The command I gave you makes it  **immutable**, you should look it up. Also, you should read what other people actually say, not what you think they say.

Comment: No need to be rude. Ok, immutable, not "read-only". That doesn't change my point that the settings are changing inside Skype, regardless of the mutability of the file.